# Confused about Redis structuring of data

Tags: redis, nosql

I have the following JSON data structure that needs to be cached in Redis:

```
{
    siteId:1,
    zoneId:1,
    adWidth:100,
    adHeight:100,
    totalVisibleAds:1,
    ads:[{
        id:1,
        link:"...",
        imageLink:"...",
        altText:"Google",
            views:100       
    },
    {
        id:1,
        link:"...",
        imageLink:"...",
        altText:"Google",
            views:100       
    }]
}
```

- I need to be able to return this structure in the "Redis" way by querying by `siteId`.
- INCR the `views` field
- Pick a random ad from the ads array
- Expire the entire object at a certain date

If I store a hash as `site:1:zone:1` how can I get just by `site:1`? Or am I just thinking about this totally wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using MongoDB in your case as you need to store nested data and query that too with nested indexes. If performance is an issue mongoDB queries are generally fast.

Refer http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-nested-sets/